# How can I check whether or not a data-testid exists on my page using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

How can I check whether or not a data-testid exists on my page using Ruby ?
I ask this because I see that there are some ways to search for selectors, but I don't know exactly if this is the correct way or not.
I'm trying to do it like this

```
expect(page).should have_no_selector("[data-testid='prepay-enroll-now-button']");



expect(page).should have_selector("[data-testid='prepay-enroll-now-button']");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is valid for a CSS attribute selector, however you shouldn't be using `should` with RSpecs expect syntax. Also, since `have_no_selector` can be changed from the normal default of CSS to XPath (or any other supported selector type) I'd recommend using `have_css` or `have_no_css` when you are using CSS.

```
expect(page).not_to have_css("[data-testid='prepay-enroll-now-button']")
```

or

```
expect(page).to have_no_css("[data-testid='prepay-enroll-now-button']")
```

Also, if you are widely using `data-testid` attributes you may want set `Capybara.test_id = 'data-testid'` which will then let you use the data-testid as the locator in other Capybara methods. For instance if 'prepay-enroll-now-button' is an actual link or button (rather than just a div with behaviors attached) you could do things like

```
click_on('prepay-enroll-now-button')
```

or

```
expect(page).not_to have_selector(:link_or_button, 'prepay-enroll-now-button')
```